# Getting image.default to use class-defined Axis functions?

Tags: oop, r, graphics

Compare the following:

```
par(mfrow = 2)
image(x=as.POSIXct(1:100, origin = "1970-1-1"), z= matrix(rnorm(100*100), 100))
plot(x=as.POSIXct(1:100, origin = "1970-1-1"), (rnorm(100)))
```

It seems like image (and so, image.default) fails to take the class-defined Axis functions into account when plotting, while plot does. This is problematic, since I'm in the process of implementing some classes with custom `pretty` and `format` specifications that would have their own way of plotting an axis, so I want to having my own axis functions be called when image is used, than always use the numeric version.

I understand there's a way round this by plotting axis manually, calling image first with `xaxt = "n"`, for instance. But this seems inconvenient and messy. Ideally, I'd like a solution that can just drop in to overlay the existing function while breaking as few things as possible. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way *is* to suppress the axes on the call to `image()` with `axes = FALSE` then add them yourself. E.g.:

```
set.seed(42)
X <- as.POSIXct(1:100, origin = "1970-1-1")
Z <- matrix(rnorm(100*100), 100)
image(x = X, z = Z, axes = FALSE)
axis(side = 2)
axis.POSIXct(side = 1, x = X)
box()
```

This can also be done using the `Axis()` S3 generic:

```
image(x = X, z = Z, axes = FALSE)
axis(side = 2)
Axis(x = X, side = 1)
box()
```

So to actually try to Answer the Question, I would wrap this into a function that automates the various steps:

```
Image <- function(x = seq(0, 1, length.out = nrow(z)),
                  y = seq(0, 1, length.out = ncol(z)),
                  z, ...) {
    image(x = X, z = Z, ..., axes = FALSE)
    Axis(x = y, side = 2, ...)
    Axis(x = X, side = 1, ...)
    box()
}
```

Write your axis functions as S3 methods for the `Axis()` generic and class `x` and `y` appropriately do that your methods are called and the above should just work. All you need to remember is to change `image()` to `Image()`.

You could also write your own `image()` method, and add your class to `x` to have it called instead of `image.default()` Depends on whether it makes sense for `x` to have a class or not?

The reason I would do this is that the only way to change `image.default()` R-wide is to edit the function and assign it to the **graphics** namespace or source your version and call it explicitly. This would need to be done each and every time you started R. A custom function could easily be sourced or added to your own local package of misc functions that you arrange to load as R is starting so that it is automagically available. See `?Startup` for details of how you might arrange for this.